# Where to put CodenameOne StateMachine Codes after converting GUI project with conversion tool

Tags: codenameone

I converted my codenameOne GUI project using conversion tool but did not know where to put my codes in StateMachine class.

And am getting some errors after conversion:

```
private static final java.util.HashMap<String, Class> formNameToClassHashMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, Class>();
```

The above code is from StateMachineBase and NetBeans hint shows

> generics are not supported in -source 1.2
>     (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)

```
super.initListModelFileList(list);
```

This code is from StateMachine class and the error message is that "cannot find symbol".

Please what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a really old project pre Java 5 support?

We generally optimized the conversion process to newer code so we assume Java 5 at the minimum. You can set the language level in the project settings to JDK 5 (notice that you can/should use JDK 8 for the build though).

Comment: I have changed the source to JDK5 and the generic is not showing again.

Is StateMachine class still in use for the converted project? If not, where should I put the codes I have within the StateMachine class?

Again, the generated gui Form classes regenerates every time I try to build the project and wipe out any changes I make, is that proper?

Comment: If you used the conversion tool it should also create a new state machine base that is permanent as an interim solution until you move to a more manual navigational structure (similar to a handcoded application). The section between the comments of the source files should be regenerated in every build this is done in the ant file in the generateGuiSources call.

Comment: OK, I see. I should now focus on converting it to manual navigational structure. Thanks.